# How to calculate the number of occurrences of each element in the 100000 vectors using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

For 100000 vectors containing 40 different numbers between 1 and 100, how to calculate the number of occurrences of each element in the 100000 vectors.

example:

A = [2 5 6 9]; B = [3 6 9 1]

the result should be if the numbers are between 1 and 10: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, 1 1 1 0 1 2 0 0 2 0]

Comment: If you have 100000 individually-named vectors, you have a problem.  You should maintain them all in a single 2D array.

Comment: Please tell me that these vectors are all contained in the same variable?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to compute the histogram of all values.
Use `hist` command for that

```
n = hist( A(:), 1:100 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a variable `A` that stores all of these vectors (like in Shai's assumption), another alternative to `hist` is to use `accumarray`.  This should automatically figure out the right amount of bins you have without specifying them like in `hist`.  Try:

```
n = accumarray(A(:), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `sparse` function to do the counting:

```
% 100000x1 vector of integers in the range [1,100]
A = randi([1 100], [100000 1]);

% 100x1 array of counts
n = full(sparse(A, 1, 1, 100, 1));
```

As [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24600572/97160) have [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24599638/97160), this should give the same result as:

```
n = histc(A, 1:100);
```

or:

```
n = accumarray(A, 1, [100 1]);
```

(note that I explicitly specify the size in the `sparse` and `accumarray` calls. That's because if for a particular vector `A` values didn't go all the way up to 100, then the counts array `n` will be shorter than 100 in length).

---

All three methods are in fact mentioned in the [tips section](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#bt4ovq2-6) of the `accumarray` doc page, which is the most flexible of all three.

> The behavior of `accumarray` is similar to that of the `histc` function.
>   Both functions group data into bins.
>
> - `histc` groups continuous values into a 1-D range using bin edges.
> - `accumarray` groups data using n-dimensional subscripts.
> - `histc` returns the bin counts using `@sum`.
> - `accumarray` can apply any function to the bins.
>
> You can mimic the behavior of `histc` using `accumarray` with `val = 1`.
>
> The `sparse` function also has accumulation behavior similar to that of `accumarray`.
>
> - `sparse` groups data into bins using 2-D subscripts, whereas `accumarray` groups data into bins using n-dimensional subscripts.
> - `sparse` adds elements that have identical subscripts into the output. `accumarray` adds elements that have identical subscripts into
>     the output by default, but can optionally apply any function to the bins.