# MATLAB: How to count the number of times a number appears in the first column of status(.sta) file?

Tags: matlab

i am having a status file which is of following format:

'bla bla

```
1     1   1     9     2    11  0.0100        0.0100     0.01000   
1     2   1     2     1     3  0.503         0.503      0.1709    
1     3   1     2     1     3  0.759         0.759      0.2563    
1     4   1     3     2     5  1.00          1.00       0.2411    
2     1   1     0     1     1  2.00          1.00       1.000     
3     1   1    10     1    11  2.20          0.200      0.2000    
3     2   1    13     2    15  2.40          0.400      0.200
4     1   1    10     1    11  2.20          0.200      0.2000    
4     2   1    10     1    11  2.20          0.200      0.2000    
4     3   1    10     1    11  2.20          0.200      0.2000
```

blah blah'

Now how can I know how many number of times 1,2,3 etc appear in the first column?

The answer for the above `.sta` file would be [4 1 2] (i.e 4 is the number of times 1 appears in the first column).

Comment: this has been asked many times here on SO.. Once you load the data, you can use any of the following ways to do the counting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2885175/97160 . Here is another one posted just yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24601403/97160

Comment: for the format you've shown above, you can load the data simply as: `load file.sta -ascii`

Comment: Error using load
Number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file C:\Intern\Slip\e.sta
must be the same as previous lines.

Comment: you didnt have the 'bla bla' parts before, so I assumed the file was all space-delimited numbers. You should explain exactly what that part you omitted is, and explain the file structure more clearly.. Anyway I think that's a separate question (how to read/parse such a file) from the current one here (how to count occurrences). But please do your research before creating a new question, there are already hundreds of questions here on Stack Overflow about loading data into MATLAB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab+file-io

Comment: This is the exact format of file. 
SUMMARY OF JOB INFORMATION:
 STEP  INC ATT SEVERE EQUIL TOTAL  TOTAL      STEP       INC OF       DOF    IF
               DISCON ITERS ITERS  TIME/    TIME/LPF    TIME/LPF    MONITOR RIKS
               ITERS               FREQ
   1     1   1    17     0    17  0.0100     0.0100     0.01000      
   3     1   1     9     2    11  2.10       0.100      0.1000    
   3     2   1    11     2    13  2.20       0.200      0.1000    
   3     3   1    23     5    28  2.30       0.300      0.1000                             
 THE ANALYSIS HAS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy, you can just look at them directly. For example if you read in your `.sta` file into a variable named `data`:

```
sum(data(:, 1) == 1)

1. data(:, 1) look at all of the first column
2. (1.) == 1  create a Boolean list of whether they equal to one
3. sum(2.)    sum up all the trues to find the total number of ones.
```

This will give you the number of `1s` in the first column.

In case you are interested in performing operations on the rest of the matrix where there are only 1s, 2s etc you can do this:

```
data_only_ones = data(data(:, 1) == 1, 2:end);
```

This will give you the remainder of the matrix for where the first columns are ones. ie. for your example:

```
1   1     9     2    11  0.0100        0.0100     0.01000   
2   1     2     1     3  0.503         0.503      0.1709    
3   1     2     1     3  0.759         0.759      0.2563    
4   1     3     2     5  1.00          1.00       0.2411
```

The thing to remember is that matlabs array indexing is **magic** and you can basically do anything.

Comment: @user3734298 If you are new then you would be much better off figuring out how to do it yourself. `Can you put the final code here` well no ... I have other things to do as well!

Comment: [fileName,pathName] = uigetfile('*.sta','Pick a file');
data = textread(fullfile(pathName,fileName),'%s','delimiter','\n');
data_only_ones = data(data(:, 1) == 1, 2:end)

this is returning a error:'Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.'